# Prove that, in a triangle $ABC$, $\vec{OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec{OC} = \vec{OO'}$, where is $O$ is the circumcenter and $O'$ is the orthocenter

Tags: vectors

> **Problem**. If $O$ is the circumcentre and $O'$ the orthocenter of a triangle $ABC$, then prove that:
>
> $$\vec{OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec{OC} = \vec{OO'}$$

I would like to know, if there is a more elementary approach to prove this identity, using purely the rules of vector addition and some geometry? Any inputs or suggestions of a simpler/alternative approach would be awesome.

I was able to prove this identity using the facts.

$(1)$ the altitude $\vec{AO'}\perp \vec{BC}$.

\begin{align}
\vec{AO'}\cdot \vec{BC} &= 0\\
(\vec{o'} - \vec{a})\cdot(\vec{c}-\vec{b}) &= 0
\end{align}

$(2)$ the perpendicular bisector $\vec{DO}\perp \vec{BC}$.

\begin{align}
\vec{DO}\cdot \vec{BC} &= 0\\
(\vec{o} - \vec{d})\cdot(\vec{c}-\vec{b}) &= 0\\
\left(\vec{o} - \frac{\vec{b}+\vec{c}}{2}\right)\cdot(\vec{c}-\vec{b}) &= 0\\
(\vec{2o} - \vec{b} - \vec{c})\cdot(\vec{c}-\vec{b}) &= 0
\end{align}

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain:

\begin{align}
(\vec{o'} + \vec{2o} - \vec{a} - \vec{b} - \vec{c})\cdot(\vec{c}-\vec{b}) &= 0
\end{align}

$\vec{c} - \vec{b}\neq 0$. Therefore, either the first term is 0, or it is a proper vector orthogonal to $\vec{BC}$.

\begin{align}
(\vec{o'} + \vec{2o} - \vec{a} - \vec{b} - \vec{c}) &= 0\\
\vec{o'} &=  \vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c} - \vec{2o}\\
\vec{o'} - \vec{o} &= \vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c} - \vec{3o}\\
\vec{OO'} &= \vec{a} - \vec{o} + \vec{b} - \vec{o} + \vec{c} - \vec{o}\\
\vec{OO'} &= \vec{OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec{OC}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Let $X$ such that $OA+OB+OC=OX$. What can we say about $X$?

Let $\vec{OA}+\vec{OB} =\vec{OD}$. Then OADB is a rombous, so $AB\bot OD$ and thus $CX||OD$, so $CX$ is an altitude. The same is true for $AX$ and $BX$ so $X=O'$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks, if $OADB$ is a parallelogram, why is the diagonal $AB \perp OD$?

Comment: @Quasar $OADB$ is a rhombus in addition to a parallelogram, because $O$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.

Comment: It is not only parallelogram. Since all sides are equal it is rombus.

Answer (score 3):

For a point $P$ such that
$$\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}=\vec{OP}$$
we get $AP\perp BC$ since
$$\begin{align}\vec{AP}\cdot\vec{BC}&=(\vec{OP}-\vec{OA})\cdot (\vec{OC}-\vec{OB})
\\\\&=(\vec{OC}+\vec{OB})\cdot (\vec{OC}-\vec{OB})
\\\\&=|\vec{OC}|^2-|\vec{OB}|^2
\\\\&=0\end{align}$$
Similarly, we get $BP\perp CA$ and $CP\perp AB$, so we see that $P=O'$ from which
$$\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}=\vec{OO'}$$ follows.